# List that contains list that contains list and so on in c#

Tags: c#, list

This is code:

```
  public class Comment
  {
    public DateTime CreateAt { get; set; }
    public Comment ParentComment { get; set;}
    public List<Comment> SubComments { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
  }
```

I'am trying to do something like on facebook. You can comment every single comment, so there will be like a tree of comments.. I'am having trouble with trying to display all the comments, precisely text. I can't figure out how to do that. If anyone could help I'll appreciate it!

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: So... what's the issue?

Comment: The only thing that crosses my mind is using for loops, but i can't have inifnite number of them.. I don't know how 'deep' the comments will be.

Comment: Are you familiar with the term "recursion?" If not, you may want to start by looking that up. (It's not strictly necessary, but it's probably the most natural thing to do if you want to visit each comment.)

Comment: @Alexander can you give me an example how would you that? Solution might be really obvious and simple but I can't see it.

Comment: @xena12 Say you have `print` method that prints the comment as a string to the console. (This simple example could be adapted to showing views in a window, or divs on an html page, or whatever you're doing). When you call `print` on one comment, you have that method print the comment it was called on, but then you make it call `print` on every SubComment as well. And they print themselves and their subcommands, and so on

Comment: [here's a good link on recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710810/list-that-contains-list-that-contains-list-and-so-on-in-c-sharp#comment76404626_44710810) (just kidding... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

Comment: Haha @MarcGravell that was real funny

Comment: I am new at programming but I know how recursion works, it just didn't cross my mind, it was a long day. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion for process each comment and their sub comments for example:

```
    public void checkComment(Comment comment)
    {
        //Check if the comment is valid
        if (comment != null)
        {
            //Do whatever you want to do with your comment for example print to console
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Comment: {0}", comment.Text));
            //Check if i have any sub comments
            if (comment.SubComments.Count > 0)
            {
                //Process each sub comment (recursive)
                comment.SubComments.ForEach(x => checkComment(x));
            }
        }
    }
```